# How can I plot a line graph from the data which miss some values in some dates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I don't understand why my plot did not show me what I had expected. My plot looks unorganized and I am not sure whether it is because the table missed some dates. How should I fix it with the code?

**my data**

```
date    count
0   2020-03-06  1
1   2020-03-17  2
2   2020-03-18  1
3   2020-03-21  1
4   2020-03-23  1
... ... ...
196 2020-12-27  25
197 2020-12-28  5
198 2020-12-29  19
199 2020-12-30  25
200 2020-12-31  23
```

**my code**

```
plt.plot(data['date'],data['count'])
plt.setp(plt.gca().xaxis.get_majorticklabels(),rotation=45)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=10))
plt.xlim('2020-03-06','2020-12-31')
plt.ylim((0,50))
plt.savefig('03_clean_tweet_count_by_month_2020.tiff', dpi=300, format='tiff', bbox_inches='tight')
```

**Result**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure without having the data to test on, but if the rows of your dataframe are not sorted properly, you could get an output like this. Try:

```
data.sort_values('date', inplace=True)
plt.plot(data['date'],data['count'])
plt.setp(plt.gca().xaxis.get_majorticklabels(),rotation=45)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=10))
plt.xlim('2020-03-06','2020-12-31')
plt.ylim((0,50))
plt.savefig('03_clean_tweet_count_by_month_2020.tiff', dpi=300, format='tiff', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: I went back and took a look at my data. The dates were incorrectly sorted. I have posted another question to get feedback on my code. I am not sure it is because of the raw data or the code.

Answer (score -1):

Try sorting your DF by Date column first, before plotting

```
data=data.sort_values(by=['date'])
plt.plot(data['date'],data['count'])
```